# Hybris interceptor is not getting triggered

Tags: interceptor, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I create `ValidateInterceptor` in below path and created bean in `custombackoffice-backoffice-spring.xml`

> C:\hybris\bin\custom\custombackoffice\backoffice\src\com\custom\backoffice\interceptor\CustomAppeasementUserValidateInterceptor.java

bean is as below

```
<bean id="customAppeasementUserValidateInterceptor" class="de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.interceptor.impl.InterceptorMapping">
    <property name="interceptor" ref="customAppeasementUserValidateInterceptor" />
    <property name="typeCode" value="Appeasement" />
</bean>
```

when I modify particular model in backoffice and click on the save button, debugger never goes to interceptor it directly saves the model.

**NOTE :- I can't write this interceptor in customcore because we can not import below services in custom core** 
import com.hybris.cockpitng.core.user.AuthorityGroupService;
import com.hybris.cockpitng.core.user.impl.AuthorityGroup;

**Why the interceptor is not getting triggered?**

Comment: Can you show us the `customAppeasementUserValidateInterceptor` bean configuration from xml ? and the class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The *bean-id* and the *mapper bean-id* are the same. Change either one. Ideally, it should be like-

```
<bean id="customAppeasementUserValidateInterceptorMapping" class="de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.interceptor.impl.InterceptorMapping">
    <property name="interceptor" ref="customAppeasementUserValidateInterceptor" />
    <property name="typeCode" value="Appeasement" />
</bean>
```

Notice the new `id` for the *mapping bean* i.e. `customAppeasementUserValidateInterceptorMapping`.

Answer (score 0):

have you done an update system from the hac or using the ant tasks? I believe interceptors need an update to be registered on the type.

Comment: update system it's only needed when the Type is new.